# What is the SLA on replication lag in a Sql Azure Failover group?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I looked into the SQL azure SLA and couldn't find this being listed explicitly:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/legal/sla/sql-database/v1_1/

In a Sql Azure failover group, the data is asynchronously synced from primary to secondary.

- What is the expected lag between the two? (as seen in practice)
- What is the worst case lag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should monitor the lag time with respect to the [RPO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-business-continuity#sql-database-features-that-you-can-use-to-provide-business-continuity) which is 5 seconds for auto-failover groups. The time period of updates that you might afford to lose is known as recovery point objective (RPO).

Sometimes replication_lag_sec on the primary database has a NULL value, which means that the primary does not currently know how far the secondary is. This typically happens after process restarts and should be a transient condition. Consider alerting the application if the replication_lag_sec returns NULL for an extended period of time. It would indicate that the secondary database cannot communicate with the primary due to a permanent connectivity failure. There are also conditions that could cause the difference between last_commit time on the secondary and on the primary database to become large. E.g. if a commit is made on the primary after a long period of no changes, the difference will jump up to a large value before quickly returning to 0. Consider it an error condition when the difference between these two values remains large for a long time.

Comment: The doc says that RPO is the time period of updates that might be lost in case of an outage. Does this imply that the replication lag <= RPO? I would assume yes, but hoping for an explicit mention of this in the docs or SLA.

Comment: "To monitor lag with respect to RPO, use replication_lag_sec column of sys.dm_geo_replication_link_status on the primary database" Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-active-geo-replication#monitoring-geo-replication-lag?wt.mc_id=MVP